# Conditional Row Color & Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: google-app-maker

I want to show my table with conditional in color. If statusx is 'Complete', it will show light green color. If it's Statusx is 'Live', it will show different color. Actually what I want is not to change background color, but also change text color.

```
@widget.datasource.item.Statusx === 'Complete' ? ['light-green','app-ListTableRow','hoverAncestor'] : @widget.datasource.item.Statusx === 'Live' ? ['green','app-ListTableRow','hoverAncestor'] : @widget.datasource.item.Statusx === 'Pending' ? ['red','app-ListTableRow','hoverAncestor'] : ['app-ListTableRow','hoverAncestor']
```

I also get some error :
Fri Jul 26 09:37:22 GMT+700 2019
(RangeError) : Maximum call stack size exceeded

```
at AllCase.Table1Panel.Table1.Table1Body.Table1Row.onDataLoad:1:19
```

at AllCase.Table1Panel.Table1.Table1Body.Table1Row.onDataLoad:1:19
at AllCase.Table1Panel.Table1.Table1Body.Table1Row.onDataLoad:1:19

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: And for color conditional, first color correct and impact to all row. But second color on impact to first row.

Comment: Where is the binding at? Presumably in row styles setting? Most of the time a call stack size is exceeded when your code gets stuck in a loop repeatedly. I’m not certain how that would happen though if this is your row binding.

Comment: Yes, it's on row styles. I want to show row based on status, for example 'Complete' will be green,  live is 'light-green' etc. So it will read the status on every row, and change the background color. Is there any way to solve this problem. ?

Comment: What is your datasource size limit? I suppose it could have to do with how many rows are in your datasource, but I’m not sure that will be the problem either.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the problem. I remove OnDataLoad value from "Reload Datasource" to "None".
Right now my problem still with color with conditional.